# Creating a new thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written a code which has 2 parts to it. The first one is a daemon thread that always monitors a data line for data exchange. The second thread is the one which filters the captured data according to certain set conditions.
I have this code as a module in another. This super set code sends out a list of parameter (the condition of filters) to the module I have written. I wanted to know is there any method by which I can create a new thread by passing these parameters while the program is running?

Thank you

Comment: Use Queue to populate your filter list. Pass the queue object in thread constructor. Queues are recommended way to read the data in threads.

Comment: I have to pass the new data everytime to a new thread, not to the same thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely should have a look at:

[multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html)

This will give you the possibility to handle any kind of you threading need.